# What do you call websites that make heavy use of vertical scrolling?

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, terminology, scrolling

This question is similar to [Why did scrolling vertically became a pattern?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/18908/why-did-scrolling-vertically-became-a-pattern)

I see a lot of modern websites moving to larger, singular pages with more content and more vertical scrolling. This is often combined with the visual marvel of [Parallax Scrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling) ([example](http://www.culturalsolutions.co.uk/)).

**Does this technique of heavy vertical scrolling have a name?**

Comment: Haven't *all* web sites scrolled vertically pretty much since the invention of the first web browsers? I'd just call it a 'web page'.

Comment: Sort of, but I'm referring to the very specific design of having links using pushState methods and so on. I feel like the example I provided is an increasing style and I feel like it should have a name.

Comment: Ah, I see. I suppose the trademark of that style is the 'sectioning' of the long page into what was traditionally separate pages. I think I'd call that something other than 'long page design' though, as there are all sorts of 'long page' web pages/sites that don't do the very purposeful horizontal sectioning like that. I'd maybe use a term that would refer to a slide-based presentation (as in essence, it's a 'deck of slides' ala PowerPoint, but stacked on one page).

Comment: dead see scrolls? totem poles?
vertically integrated? eyescrapers?

Comment: @cris I vote 'eysecrapers'!

Comment: This pattern was extended to the point of infinite scrolling (e.g. Google Images).

Comment: @DA01, for what it's worth: "Once upon a time, page-level vertical scrolling was not permitted on AOL."

  [1]: http://boxesandarrows.com/blasting-the-myth-of-the-fold/

Comment: `Infinite scrolling`, `Single page`, `Automatic paging`, `Click-free paging`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's quite literal: [Long page design](https://www.google.com/search?q=long+page+design) (google search for the same term).

Comment: Also note that "Single page design" is a related term--not quite synonymous, but often this style involves putting everything on one page.

Comment: You should really expand on this answer; "Link-only" answers are not very helpful here and "Google it" is not a very good explanation (however correct). Also, remember, Jeff Atwood says [Bring the content here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/602/21267).

Answer (score 4):

**Single Page** is probably the most apt term.

If you go to [Awwwards.com](http://www.awwwards.com/search?search%5Btags%5D%5Bsingle-page%5D=single-page&search%5Bsotd%5D=1&search%5Bhonorable%5D=1) you'll see they call it "single page" and then provide 800+ examples. Enjoy!

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: [Bring the content here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/602/21267)

Answer (score -2):

It's called a parallax design. Search online for "define parallax website" and you'll get a number of examples and definitions. FWIW I was banging my head, trying to remember this word, found this question but no one (yet) had the answer. Mercifully, the word then popped in my head: parallax.

Comment: "Parallax scrolling is a special scrolling technique in computer graphics, wherein background images move by the camera slower than foreground images, creating an illusion of depth in a 2D video game and adding to the immersion." -Wikipedia

Comment: It is often combined with Parallax scrolling (as described in the question), but the common term is long page, single page or one page design.

Comment: Hi Gustav, we're actually both right based on additional research. This type of page has multiple names. While it is called parallax pages by some people, as you point out that term is not 100% accurate.

YMMV in other words depending on your situation. If your shop and clients called it parallax, that works. If your shop and clients use the more precise terms you point out, that's fine, too. Both terms will get you lots of examples online. Sorry for any confusion.